# Alter table using Nexusdb embedded database in Delphi

Tags: delphi, embedded-database, nexusdb

I am creating a small tool to update database table. So i want to add columns to table using embedded database (using alias path- without running Nxserver) database. I did it successfully but table can't be opened from Enterprise manager.
It says "incompatible stream". I can load table to a dbgrid using embedded database. 
it might be a version issue between embedded database and server. But how can i do this for any version?

Comment: This q needs an MCVE (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Btw, what do Nexus Tech Support say?

Comment: I didn't post this there...

Answer (score 0):

Restructure upgrades a table file to the table version of the server engine that performed the restructure. In this case the server engine that's embedded in your application.

If this table version is newer than the table version supported by the nxServer or EM (if using the internal server) you are later using to try and access this table, then you may get this error.

If you are going to access the table through a specific nxServer later, you should be using that server to perform the restructure, not the embedded engine in your program.